# Wordpress - display certain categories on homepage

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been trying to alter my current code, but it makes no sense to me (it doesn't do what I was told it does). All I want to do is only display posts with category 13 on my homepage and I want to be able to add multiple categories to a post.

- Post 1 (Category 13 and 1) = displayed on homepage
- Post 2 (Category 13 and 4 and 5) = displayed on homepage
- Post 3 (Category 6 and 1) = not visible on homepage
- Post 4 (Category 2) = not visible on homepage

This is my current code to only show category 13 on my homepage, if another category is added to the post it won't be displayed at all.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary">
<div id="content" role="main">

<?php
    if (is_home()) {
        query_posts("cat=-6,-4,-1,-11");
    }
?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>
    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
    'cat' => 13,
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged);
    query_posts($args);
?>

<?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
    <header class="entry-header">
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Geen berichten beschikbaar', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h1>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
    <p><?php _e( 'Helaas, er zijn nog geen gearchiveerde berichten in deze categorie. ', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></p>
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </article><!-- #post-0 -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This looks basically correct. Where did you place this in your theme file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking way too hard at this code. You don't need to exclude anything, you just need to include cat `13`, which will include everything that is in cat `13`; *even* if it is in other categories as well. Just run a regular [`WP_Query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) like so:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary">
<div id="content" role="main">

<?php
    if (is_home()) {
        // The Query
        $the_query = new WP_Query("cat=13, paged=".get_query_var('paged'));
    }
?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>
    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
    <header class="entry-header">
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Geen berichten beschikbaar', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h1>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
    <p><?php _e( 'Helaas, er zijn nog geen gearchiveerde berichten in deze categorie. ', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></p>
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </article><!-- #post-0 -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

(had to add a few charachters or I could not edit, sorry :P)

Comment: So first of all, use `WP_Query()` instead of `query_posts()` - and second, without server access I can't affirm this code works. However, you can read up on `WP_Query()` [HERE](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). and you basically need a simple `$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=13' )` to show the posts you want

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<?php
  $temp = $wp_query; 
  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
  $wp_query->query('showposts=6&cat=13'.'&paged='.$paged);
?>
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

    Your stuff goes here...

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php 
  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = $temp;  // Reset
?>
```

Comment: Will this also include posts that have category 13 but also another category? (For example Post1 - Cat 13 & 1; Post2 - Cat 13; Post3 - Cat 5; Post4 - Cat 13 & 2; Only posts 1 2 and 4 should be visible then)

Comment: Yes this will include all the posts tagged to category13, no matter if it is also tagged to some other categories...

Comment: Ok I will try this! This is for the main index template correct? and what do you mean by `Your stuff goes here`?

Comment: Your stuff goes here --- mean whatever you want to display in the loop like the_content() or the_title() etc....

Comment: This causes my site to crash :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<?php
global $post;
if (is_home()) {
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'category' => 13 );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php the_content( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>); ?>
            </div>
    <?php endforeach;
}
?>
```

This will display the title and content. If you want additional information like date, author, category, tag etc, you may have to use other template tags. Also if you want to style these differently, then you have to use appropriate CSS.

Comment: This just creates a list and doesn't display the posts as they normally would. I think you mistakenly thought I wanted to create a list of posts, but this was just to make my point in what cases I want it work. If you could implement this, you're granted 50 credits :)

Comment: I was concentrating more on retrieving the list of posts rather than displaying them. Once you have retrieved them, you can display them in what ever way you want. You just have to add more template tags. Anyway now I have added title and post content. You can add more if you want.

Comment: ... or let me know the list of fields you want to be displayed and I can update the code with them.